# Best transference to make in WebSphere MQ FTE when the source directory is constantly getting new files

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I just want to know what is the best transference (schedule, using trigger files, using transfer templates) to configure if the directory that has the source files is constantly getting new files:
 - A schedule transfer could be good, but what amount of time must be set in order to grant that the files will not be overwritten or will be transferred again?
 - A trigger file could be useful too, but how do you do when you always have new files? do you need to write an external program to help you with that?

In this case the size of the files is variable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best functionality to start a transfer (fteCreateTransfer command, the WebSphere MQ Explorer Managed File Transfer plug-in GUI, Apache ANT script, scheduled transfer, resource monitor, etc) depends entirely on what your needs are and the environment in which your running.

In answer to your first question, a scheduled transfer will **not** being another instance if an existing instance of that scheduled transfer has not completed. However, if you plan to overwrite the source files when you want to transfer new ones and want to know how long to wait before doing so to ensure they have already been transferred, well, how long is a piece of string? If the network goes down between the agents and the transfer enters recovery it could take any amount of times for the network connection to be reestablished and for the transfer to recover and continue.

In terms of resource monitoring and trigger files, you need to design you resource monitor and solution appropriately for what you want to achieve. If you have filenames that adopt a certain naming convention, you might like to try triggering on the files you want to transfer, and using a feature called "Variable Substitution" offered by the resource monitor to ensure the file that triggered the monitor is the one that is then transferred. How to do this is documented in the WebSphere MQ FTE Information Center.

Comment: As you say it really depends on the situation, i have found one of the IBM Redbooks about WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition and it explain different scenarios and explain how to implement a solution using WebSphere MQ FTE. Here is the link to the Redbook:
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247760.html?Open